# C# - Como criar um contrato de implementação com subclasses a serem implementadas?

Tags: c#, interface, subclasse

Gostaria de criar uma interface (chamei de InterfaceX)

```
interface InterfaceX
{
...
}
```

Onde sua futura implementação retornasse a seguinte estrutura:

```
ClasseDaInterfaceX.ClasseA.Metodo1daClasseA(parametro);
ClasseDaInterfaceX.ClasseA.Metodo2daClasseA(parametro);
ClasseDaInterfaceX.ClasseB.Metodo1daClasseB(parametro);
...
```

Ou seja: o resultado seria uma classe com duas classes aninhadas.
Porem, que os métodos das classes ClasseA e ClasseB também precisem ser implementados.

Segue o exemplo concreto:

Imagine um sistema que pode usar como "base de dados", qualquer coisa.
Num determinado lugar posso usar SQL Server.
Num outro lugar Firebird.
Num outro posso usar um webservice ou mesmo um arquivos texto!

A implementação dessa DLL dependerá das condições que encontrarei no lugar que usará o sistema.

Então preciso criar uma interface com todas as rotinas, suas entradas e seus retornos, para que as futuras DLLs possam implementa-la, seguindo assim o contrato.

Porem, imagine que esse sistema pode ter centenas de métodos de acesso a base de dados.

Imagine uma interface com 250 métodos, por exemplo. Ao meu ver, é bizarro.

Então eu pensei: será que não existe uma forma de eu organizar essa interface com "subclasses" ou com "subinterfaces".

Seria algo como o exemplo abaixo:

```
interface IDatabase
{

    interface ClienteDB
    {
        public bool Create(Cliente);
        public Cliente Read();
        public Cliente Update();
        public bool Delete();
    }

    interface FornecedorDB
    {
        public bool Create(Fornecedor);
        public Fornecedor Read();
        public Fornecedor Update();
        public bool Delete();
    }

    ...    
}
```

Com isso, teria um contrato bem definido e relativamente organizado, que forçaria a implementação da DLL seguindo a mesma organização.

E o acesso ao métodos ficaria assim:

Database.Clientes.Create(...);

Existe alguma forma de criar uma interface assim em C#?

Comment: Explica isso melhor, faça um exemplo mais concreto.

Comment: Reforço o comentário do Maniero, sem explicar melhor não tem como ajudar.

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta com um exemplo concreto.

Comment: O que você quer, se é que deu para entender, não tem como e nem faz sentido. Se não quer fazer fazer algo bizarro não faça, o problema não é o código, é a ideia errada. Parece que está querendo reinventar o Entity Framework do jeito errado.

Comment: Eu não sei o quão flexivel o Entity Framework é. Tem gente que ainda usa sistemas em clipper, por exemplo. Será que o EF acessa .dbf, arquivos binários, etc? O entity eu posso usar numa implementação específica da DLL, para mapear as tabelas, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia!

Você pode usar um Design pattern conhecido com Rrepository, pois ele abstrai o armazenamento do modelo.

Esse Design pattern tem como objetivo isolar o código de persistência de dados das regras de negócios assim quando for necessário alterar o banco ficará mais simples sendo apenas necessário modificar o repositório.

Exemplo de código:

```
public interface Repository<T> {
    bool Create(T item);

    T update(T item);

    bool remove(T item);

   T Read(int id);
}


public class ClienteRepository : Repository<Cliente>
{
    public bool Create(Cliente item){
        //DB insert
    }
    public Cliente update(Cliente item) {
        //DB update
    }

    public Cliente update(Cliente item) {
        //DB delete
    }

    public Cliente update(Cliente item) {
        //DB delete
    }

    public Cliente Read(int id){
        //DB Select
    }
}


public class Cliente
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Saiba mais sobre o Design pattern nos links abaixo:

- https://medium.com/falafel-software/implement-step-by-step-generic-repository-pattern-in-c-3422b6da43fd
- https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html
- http://www.macoratti.net/11/10/net_pr1.htm
- https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Obrigado!
Vou estudar esse pattern.